# Prevent print() from outputting list indices in R

Tags: r, list, loops, printing

I have a [list](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B1krGGny7BduMWZjZTY2OTUtOTk4Yy00MGQ0LWJlNDMtODk3MGE5ODQzMmJk&hl=en&authkey=CM2k-sYM) containing six plots, made like this:

```
voi=c('inadist','smldist','lardist')

plist <- llply(voi, 
    function(v,df,s) {
        list(   
            assign(
                paste(v,'.violin'), 
                bwplot(groupname~df[,which(colnames(df)==v)]|fCycle*fPhase, 
                    data=df, 
                    groups=groupname, col=rainbow(1), box.ratio=3,
                    main=paste('Distribution of ', v, ' by Treatment and Cycle'),
                    sub=s, xlab=v, panel=panel.violin)),
            assign(
                paste(v,'.hexbin'),
                hexbinplot(df[,which(colnames(df)==v)]~starttime|groupname, 
                    data=df, xlab='Time(s)',main= paste('Distribution of ',v,' by Treatment'),
                    sub=s,ylab=v, aspect=0.5, colramp=redgrad.pal, layout=c(2,4)))

            )
    },data,meta$exp_name)
```

If I print the list, `print(plist)`, the plots are output to the graphical device, then the indices are output to the console resulting in this:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]

[[1]][[2]]


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]

[[2]][[2]]


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]

[[3]][[2]]
```

Because I am coding a webapp, I need to control console output quite strictly. So far the only way I can output the plots without outputting the indices is like this:

```
for(p in plist) 
    for(i in p) 
        print(i)
```

Is there a more efficient way of getting what I need?

Comment: I'll try to help but can you *please* provide a self-contained mockup data set?

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel: I've added a file produced using `save(plist,file=fn)`  Thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 7):

You can cheat with `capture.output`:

```
dummy <- capture.output(print(plist))
```

or without creating a new variable

```
invisible(capture.output(print(plist)))
```

---

By the way, reproducible example look like this:

```
require(lattice)
plist <- list(
    list(bwplot(rnorm(10)),bwplot(rnorm(10))),
    list(bwplot(rnorm(10)),bwplot(rnorm(10))),
    list(bwplot(rnorm(10)),bwplot(rnorm(10)))
)
```

Comment: A reproducible example would set a seed, first ;)

Comment: @Greg touché. I should use `1:10` ;)

Comment: +1 -- good trick for the answer, and nice hint for the reproducible example.

Comment: I've added a link to an R file of the actual list. It's at https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B1krGGny7BduMWZjZTY2OTUtOTk4Yy00MGQ0LWJlNDMtODk3MGE5ODQzMmJk&hl=en&authkey=CM2k-sYM