# Print character string without indices in R

Tags: r

I have looked at the answers to [Print list without line numbers in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905041/print-list-without-line-numbers-in-r) and [Prevent print() from outputting list indices in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968693/prevent-print-from-outputting-list-indices-in-r), but neither seems to prevent R from printing a character string with indices are the left.

Input:

```
foo = "10 & 1.832171"    
print(foo, row.names=F, quote=F)
```

Output:

```
[1] 10 & 1.832171
```

Desired Output:

```
 10 & 1.832171
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Can you please explain the difference between your output and desired output?

Comment: @Metrics - Notice the `[1]` at the beginning of the code box displayed beneath "Output:"

Comment: @ Josh: I didn't notice that. Thanks.

Comment: Alternatives to print: `sprintf(fmt, str)`, or `message(...)`, or `cat(...)`, or stamp to file with `write(`, or `sink(`, then copy file to stdout with `cat(`.  Also you can write bytes directly to stdout or stderr.  Or call C functions like cout from R.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
> foo = "10 & 1.832171"       
> cat(foo)
10 & 1.832171
```

Comment: You have to manually include `\n` in the string if you want to use `cat` though.

Comment: And for this - here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46198371/1089239

Comment: `cat` doesn't seem to handle arrays...

Comment: @not2qubit Loop over your array and cat the individual values then

Comment: So a better solution is:
`paste(string_vector, collapse = '\n') %>% cat()`.

Comment: I confirm that this also works in R Markdown in a situation where you're dealing with a single number of something. I used this to express the number of NA's (without the index) in certain data in an R Markdown report. Excellent, thank you!